# Can JMockit work with scala?

Tags: scala, junit, jmockit

I googled little bit and it seems for me that it's possible. But when I tried like this:

```
class Calc {
  def sum(first: Int, second: Int) = {
    first + second
  }
}
```

And "test" class:

```
class CalcTest {
  @Test
  def testSum(@Mocked test: Calc) {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
      test.sum(2, 3)
      times = 1
      result = Int.box(5)
    }}
    Assert.assertEquals(5, test.sum(2, 3))
  }
}
```

I have an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class mockit.Invocations
>   from class com.kvg.client.CalcTest$$anon$1    at
>   com.kvg.client.CalcTest$$anon$1.(CalcTest.scala:11)     at
>   com.kvg.client.CalcTest.testSum(CalcTest.scala:9)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Can JMockit work with with scala? And if it can what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried JMockIt with Scala about a year ago without success. I'm not sure whether it can be done. JMockIt does a lot of byte code manipulation and I doubt it takes into account the sorts of tricks Scala utilizes in byte code.

Answer (score 0):

JMockit does not support Scala or any language other than Java on the JVM

https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/pull/358

> Finally, there were already requests in the past to add support for
>   other JVM languages. I remember of Scala (ScalaMock), Extend, and
>   Kotlin. If Groovy support was accepted, how to deny support for other
>   languages? And keeping in mind that the JMockit project never intended
>   to support anything other than the JVM (ie, not stuff like Dalvik) and
>   the Java language.